# after archive xamarin android signalr not work

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, signalr

i working with signalr in xamarin 
until in debug mode signalr is working but make and install package not work

1. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
   Parameter name: key
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.AuthorizeRequest(IRequest request)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapMiddleware.d__0.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.d__5.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.d__2.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

code:
  readonly HubConnection HubConnection = new HubConnection(GetRestService.Baseurl);
        public async Task Connect()
        {

```
        try
        {
            var hubproxy = HubConnection.CreateHubProxy("MyMarkethub");
            var rest = new GetRestService { Serverkey = RegisterModel.UserRegisterModel.ServerKey };
            var snd = rest.CodeingData(
                new
                {
                    Id = RegisterModel.UserRegisterModel.RegServerId,
                    RegisterModel.UserRegisterModel.Password
                }, "signalr");
            HubConnection.Headers.Add("userid", RegisterModel.UserRegisterModel.RegServerId.ToString());
            HubConnection.Headers.Add("sendata", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(snd));
            var notify = new NotiManager(_activity);


            hubproxy.On<SendData>("EditCustomer", async m =>
            {
                var tbl = new CustomerTbl();
                await tbl.AsyncWithserver(m.DecriptData());
                notify.Intent = new Intent(_activity, typeof(UserActivity));
                notify.ShowCustomerProfileBuyOff();
            });
            hubproxy.On<SendData>("BuyOff", m =>
            {
                notify.Intent = new Intent(_activity, typeof(OffActivity));

                notify.ShowCustomerProfileBuyOff();
            });
            hubproxy.On<SendData>("Buy", m =>
            {
                notify.Intent = new Intent(_activity, typeof(ShowFactorActivity));
                ShowFactorActivity.BuyData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Buy>(m.DecriptData());

                try
                {
                    _activity.StartActivity(typeof(ShowFactorActivity));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);

                }

            });
            await HubConnection.Start();
            return 1;
        }
        catch (HubException ex)
        {
            var d = ex.Message;
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var d = ex.Message;
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try disabling the `Linker` in the `Release` configuration and try it again, if it runs fine then review: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/

Comment: after disable linker work but size apk is large

Comment: Yes it will be, use the Linker information on Xamarin's website...

Comment: can you help me about this