# Sudden Death of SignalR - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, signalr

I have been bashing my head to figure out what happened, My SignalR server seems to be working fine, I can use the JQuery to connect to the Hub as following

```
 $.connection.hub.url = "https://mysite.azure/signalr/hubs/";        
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        var hub = $.connection.airP2P;
        var token = "abcd";
        $.connection.hub.qs = { 'access_token': token };
        console.log("Connecting.....");
        $.connection.hub.start({ jsonp: isChrome })
            .done(function () {
                console.log("Connected to Hub!");                
            })
            .fail(function () { 
                console.log("Could not Connect to signal R hub!"); });
```

but not form my Android app, It suddenly stopped working and giving me 500 Internal Server Error as following

```
StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, 
Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent, 
Headers:
{
  Cache-Control: private
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=9865c22a2d9f2f551f361f12a9fa85ff22f916bd5bee09cf0caa99ac24419d10;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=mysite.azure
  Date: Wed, 05 Aug 2020 06:55:09 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}
```

My code is the following

```
var querystringData = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
   { "access_token", User_Auth_Token }
};

hubConnection = new HubConnection("https://mysite.azure/signalr", querystringData);
mhubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("myHubName");
await hubConnection.Start();
```

The exact same code was working fine, just suddenly stopped working, any idea?

Comment: Look at the server logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @CodeCaster, looking at the Server logs I found this error

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2.FindEntry(TKey key)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.AuthorizeRequest(IRequest request)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(IDictionary2 environment) at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapMiddleware.d__0.MoveNext()
```

This happens when you run Xamarin app with `Linker` as described in the following question

[after archive xamarin android signalr not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45627419/after-archive-xamarin-android-signalr-not-work)

To resolve this I had to Disable Linker in my Build Settings. I am still not sure how to properly resolve this issue as Disabling Linker drastically increases the APK size

More info can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-sg/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker